How to change rgb values using numpy where function in python
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

target_file = r'D:\rgb_test\C\test.tga'
img = Image.open(target_file)
basePixel = np.array(img)

old_rgb_value = (255, 0, 0)
new_rgb_value = (57, 57, 57)


I opened an image using PIL. And then changed it into numpy array. I want to find index which matches old_rgb_value.(255, 0, 0) So I got the result as below.(array[0], array[0])
I know I can change one value using where function.
But how can I change three values all together?
[255, 0, 0] -> [57, 57, 57]

I used this code. And I got that result.
np.where(
(basePixel[:, :, 0] == old_rgb_value[0]) & (basePixel[:, :, 1] == old_rgb_value[1]) & (
basePixel[:, :, 2] == old_rgb_value[2]))

The essential thing here is that the complete RGB triplet has to match. You can achieve this, for example, via np.all(base_pixel == old_rgb_value, axis=-1), and then using the resulting boolean array for adjusting the corresponding positions in base_pixel¹. Together, this would look as follows:
import numpy as np

base_pixel = np.asarray([[[255,   0,   0],
                          [255, 255, 255]],
                         [[255, 255, 255],
                          [255, 255, 255]]])

old_rgb_value = (255, 0, 0)
new_rgb_value = (57, 57, 57)

base_pixel[np.all(base_pixel == old_rgb_value, axis=-1)] = new_rgb_value
print(base_pixel)
# >>> [[[ 57  57  57]
#       [255 255 255]]
#
#      [[255 255 255]
#       [255 255 255]]]

¹) I changed the name basePixel from your question to base_pixel in my answer; for two reasons: (1) Python naming conventions prefer lowercase names, separated by underscores, for variables. (2) For all other variables in your code snippet, you follow the lower-case-with-underscore naming convention, so the name basePixel is inconsistent with your remaining code.

It works perfectly. Thank you so much!!
